# SimpleDateFormat does not parse correctly

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, timeofday

```
  String current = "07:00:00.160"

  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 

  DateList.add(df2.parse(current));
```

Returns [Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 GMT 1970]

I have tried this as well

```
    Date currentdate;
    currentdate = df2.parse(current);
    df2.format(currentdate);
    DateList.add(currentdate);
```

Returns also

[Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 GMT 1970]

and I have also tried using `df2.setLenient(false);`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The result that you report is the one that I would have expected. Which result did you expect?

Comment: Looks correct. What’s the problem?

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). I strongly recommend you use the [solution by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140388/10819573).

Answer (score 2):

### java.time.LocalTime

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work. The class to use for time of day is `LocalTime`.

We don’t even need to specify a formatter for parsing your string since it is in the default format for a time of day (also laid down in the ISO 8601 standard).

```
    String current = "07:00:00.160";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(current);
    System.out.println(time);
```

Outout:

> 07:00:00.160

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)